# Are required keys in options for custom plugin to Chart.js possible? (Concerning TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, chart.js

[Cross-posted to https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/discussions/10864].

I'm using Chart.js with React and TypeScript. Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73401721/8550319), I've typed my custom plugin options in an `index.d.ts`-file, like so:

```
export type MyPluginOptions = {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
  };

declare module 'chart.js' {
  interface PluginOptionsByType<TType extends ChartType> {
    myPlugin?: MyPluginOptions;
  }
}
```

The problem is that Chart.js has this wrapped (I think) in a `_DeepPartialObject<>`, which means that `foo` and `bar` become optional against my intention. Can I somehow counteract this, or how should I deal with it? I would like all keys to be required. I feel like I should be able to utilize TypeScipt's `Required<>` somehow, but I can't seem to figure out how.

---

For more context, I then have something like this defined:

```
const myChartOptions: ChartOptions<'bar'> = {
  // other options,
  plugins: {
    myPlugin: {
      foo: 'something',
      bar: 'something else',
    },
  },
};
```

Here TypeScript is fine with `foo` and/or `bar` missing. Then, when defining the action of the plugin, one thing I've tried looks something like:

```
const myPlugin : Plugin<'bar'> = {
  id: 'my-plugin',
  afterDraw: function (chart, _args, options: MyPluginOptions) {
    if (options) {
      const x = options.foo;
      const y = options.bar;
      // more code
  };
};
```

Since I "cheated" by writing `options: MyPluginOptions`, TypeScript infers that `foo` and `bar` exist. But it also infers that `options` exists, which it could not, so that's can be a problem. Alternatively, I could have

```
const myPlugin : Plugin<'bar'> = {
  id: 'my-plugin',
  afterDraw: function (chart) {
    const options = chart.plugins?.myPlugin as MyPluginOptions;
    if (options) {
      const x = options.foo;
      const y = options.bar;
      // more code
  };
};
```

This mostly gives me what I want, but doesn't provide non-partial type checking when setting the options.

---

Other workarounds I can image include:

- Setting the options in an unrelated object to circumvent the Chart.js typing entirely.
- Actually treating them as optional keys and define default behavior on undefined keys. (Seems unnecessary in my use case, but I suspect this is the intention of the Chart.js team?).

I would love to get some more insight, especially if I'm missing the mark on the preferred way to do things.

Comment: In TS 4.9+ we have `satisfies` which would do exactly what you want.

Comment: Consider asking on https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/discussions , there is a moderate chance it's either not implemented by whatever reason, a bug, or considered a featuere

Comment: @caTS That does seem like a nice feature.

Comment: @Dimava Thanks for the suggestion, I've done that now :)